Relation between density of 1's in a binary sequence and the gap between the two disjoint subsequence of 1's and 0's
Let $a_i$ be a sequence of 0 and 1, and let $r_j$ be the density of 1 within $\{a_1,\dots,a_j\}$, i.e., $$r_j=\frac{\#\{i\leq j:a_i=1\}}{j}.$$
Let $m_k$ be the sequence of positive integer where $a_{m_k}=1$, and $n_k$ the sequence where $a_{n_k}=0$. E.g., given the sequence $$1101110011101$$ then $\{m_k\}$ is $\{1,2,4,5,6,9,10,11,13,\dots\}$, and $\{n_k\}$ is $\{3,7,8,12,\dots\}$. Is there a relation between $r_n$ and $|m_k-n_k|$?
As an example, consider the case when $n_k>m_k$ for all $k$, i.e., there are more 1's than 0's in the sequence $\{a_i\}$. If for some $M>0$, we have $n_k-m_k\leq M\log k$ for all $k$, then it is not hard to show that $$r_{n_k}\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{M\log k}{2k}.$$
If $r_j>\frac{1}{2}$ and decreases to $\frac{1}{2}$, can we conclude that $n_k-m_k$ can have at most sub-linear growth? This seems correct intuitively.

Seems close to Shannon communication theory, in particular theorems about being sure of uniqueness of a "End of Message" special value.
